# Cannot access mvn command from bash script

Tags: bash, maven

I want to run the following script as:

```
bash ./scripts/startapp.sh
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
str=$HOSTNAME
PREV_IFS=$IFS
IFS=. components=(${str})
ORIGINAL_DIRECTORY=`pwd`
REP_DIRECTORY=$ORIGINAL_DIRECTORY/src/main/resources
for part in "${components[@]}"
do
  PATH=$REP_DIRECTORY/"$part"
  REP_DIRECTORY=$PATH
done
IFS=$PREV_IFS
CONFIG_PATH=$REP_DIRECTORY/application.yaml
# Below is the final command I want to run from the terminal
`SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=$CONFIG_PATH mvn spring-boot:run`
```

I am getting

```
mvn: command not found
```

Without starting the script, I can use mvn spring-boot:run without any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have defined:

- `M2_HOME` pointing to the base directory of your Maven installation
- `PATH` must include `$M2_HOME/bin`

In your script you're overwriting the value of `PATH` on every iteration. You should change it to:

```
PATH=$PATH:$REP_DIRECTORY/"$part"
```